# hsqldb merge with an IDENTITY column

Tags: hsqldb

I have the following hsqldb database:

```
 CREATE TABLE t (id INT IDENTITY, code VARCHAR(10), description VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO t (code, description) VALUES ('C1', 'dining table'), ('C2', 'deck chair')
```

I need to add entries, only if they do not already exist in the table.
I would like to do this in one step (instead of a SELECT step to find out if the entry is in the table, and a second step to INSERT it if that's not the case)

hsqldb has the MERGE operation for this.
however, the problem is that I have a id IDENTITY column that hsqldb should automatically take care of setting the value,
and I don't know how to tell this to the MERGE operation.

```
 MERGE INTO t USING (VALUES(3, 'C3', 'conference table')) 
   AS vals(x,y,z) ON t.code = vals.y
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.x, vals.y, vals.z
```

This would work, but I had to give the id (3), and I need that it is hsqldb that automatically sets the id (just as in the INSERT operation above). I would need something like this:

```
 MERGE INTO t (code, description) USING (VALUES('C3', 'conference table')) 
   AS vals(x,y) ON t.code = vals.x
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES vals.x, vals.y
```

but this query does not work because the MERGE operation does not allow to specify which columns I am working on "(code, description)".

how can I achieve it?

ps: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_merge_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the INSERT documentation.

You can use the keyword DEFAULT instead of a value. This inserts the default value of a column, or if the column is defined as IDENTITY, the next generated value.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but potentially this should work.

This is specification

```sql
MERGE INTO <target table> [ [ AS ] <merge correlation name> ] 
USING <table reference> ON <search condition>
<merge operation specification>
```

Now focus on `<merge operation specification>`. This should be expanded into *WHEN MATCHED THEN* and/or *WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN* where you put `<merge insert specification>`

Which should be regular INSERT statement with. To let HSQL to generate identity you could do 2 things (again theoretical):

- **Ommit PK column**

  ```sql
  INSERT [ <left paren> <insert column list> <paren right> ]
  [ <override clause> ] VALUES <merge insert value list>
  ```

  So in your case

  ```sql
  MERGE INTO t USING (VALUES(3, 'C3', 'conference table')) 
  AS vals(x,y,z) ON t.code = vals.y
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (code,description) VALUES vals.y, vals.z
  ```
- Using **identity()** method

  ```sql
  MERGE INTO t USING (VALUES(3, 'C3', 'conference table')) 
  AS vals(x,y,z) ON t.code = vals.y
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES identity(), vals.y, vals.z
  ```

I will try to test this hypothesis, while I need to something similar.